# Was there any talk in the U.S. to reform the legal system and not rely on juries during patent litigation cases?

Tags: united-states, law

The legal processes and structures vary from one country to another. In some jurisdictions, patent disputes are resolved by specialized patent courts or judges without the involvement of a jury. The choice of a jury or non-jury system depends on the legal traditions and systems in place within each specific country. In the U.S., there's a jury, but in other countries we often have judges who are specialized in patents instead. Was there any talk in the U.S. to reform the legal system and not rely on juries during patent litigation cases?

Comment: What's special about patent law? The jury isn't expected to an expert in criminal law in criminal cases, nor in contract law or torts in other cases.  The *judge* is expected to be an expert in the law and, where necessary explain any legal points to to jury.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having juries decide on facts (rather than law) is seen as a guard against corruption.  Having a closed network of specialists would make it easily corruptible by large financial interests.
It's not perfect.  But it's not nothing.